# How to serve a next js application with gorilla mux in Golang instead of the native go http package?

Tags: go, mux

I have a go backend and inside my controllers i have a routes.go that uses gorilla mux router. How can i serve a static next js application using gorilla mux?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? And please do read [ask].

Comment: Yes you are right, I need to read that! Thanks for the tip! Do you happen to know how to proxy the static next.js app requests to the golang backend?

Answer (score 1):

s.Router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("nextjs/dist")))
That's how i managed to serve the static next.js